# Changed the java.library.path property. How to do I change it back to its default value?

Tags: java, windows, command-line, java-native-interface

I am working on a project that involves using the JNI and was messing around with the java.library.path property to fix my java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError with no results. I have moved around the dll that I need the JNI to open. I believe that I need to change the java.library.path property back to its default value.

I changed the java.library.path property by using java with the System.setProperty("java.library.path", ""); statment.

I initially changed it to where the directory where the dll was located. To change it back I tried inputting "PATH" and "%PATH%" as the second argument in the setProperty statement.

I outputted a System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); statement to see what the value was while I was changing it around. None of my attempts to change it back have worked and I still get the java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

I just need help changing back the java.library.path back to its default value. :)

Comment: Did you change your `java.library.path` setting system-wide or only for one invocation of your program?

Comment: You can't change this value such way. The only option is to mess around using reflection. The only option is to use -Djava.library.path during application startup. However, if you have very specific case, you can always play with a wrapper code. Take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018/

Comment: @Botije I changed it for the one invocation of the program.